# Procedimiento Almacenado no realiza insercion

Tags: c#, sql, .net, server, core

tengo este SP :

```
USE [Empleados]
GO

ALTER Procedure [dbo].[SP_INS_CARGOS]
@Descr_Cargo  varchar(50)
As
Begin
    if not Exists(Select Descr_Cargo from Cargos where Descr_Cargo = @Descr_Cargo)
    begin
      INSERT INTO [dbo].[Cargos] (Descr_Cargo,Elim) VALUES (@Descr_Cargo, 'N')
    end

y al invocarlo desde la aplicacion :

 public void CrearCargo(string DescrCargo){
        Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"SP_INS_CARGOS {DescrCargo}");
 }
```

me envía el siguiente mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el problema es que cuando envío una cadena sin espacio entre medio (para separar palabras) no me da ningún problema.

Comment: PARAMETRIZA TUS QUERIES o vas a terminar conociendo a Bobby Tables.

Comment: parece que falta algo en el SP, no encuentro por ningún lado alguna referencia a "General"

Comment: no, no hace falta, lo que pasa que "general" es la palabra que se devuelve, es parte de la cadena que que se envía al tratar de realizar la inserción

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya, solucionado.
Cambié de

```cs
Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"SP_INS_CARGOS {DescrCargo}");
```

A:

```cs
Database.ExecuteSql($"SP_INS_CARGOS {DescrCargo}");
```

¡y funcionó!

Comment: No olvides lo que te han dicho en el comentario de tu pregunta: _PARAMETRIZA TUS QUERIES o vas a terminar conociendo a Bobby Tables._ Y si no sabés a qué se refiere, [esta es la explicación](https://xkcd.com/327/) :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public void CrearCargo(string DescrCargo)
{
    Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("EXEC SP_INS_CARGOS @p0", DescrCargo);
}

  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT Descr_Cargo FROM Cargos WHERE LOWER(Descr_Cargo) = LOWER(@Descr_Cargo))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Cargos] (Descr_Cargo, Elim) VALUES (@Descr_Cargo, 'N')
    END
```

Comment: i cual seria el objeto de convertir a minúsculas???

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta

Comment: Ya Intente con la corrección y me sigue enviando el mismo error